# isNetworkConnected() Problem with Android Pie 9.0

Tags: java, android

I'm using this code to check if the network is connected or not.
it is working perfectly on all Android versions up to **8.1**
but since Android Pie, it always shows that I'm not connected!

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo == null || !networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            onUpdateNetworkStatus(false);
            return false;
        }

        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final URL url = new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204");
                    final HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                    httpURLConnection.connect();
                    onUpdateNetworkStatus(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 204 && httpURLConnection.getContentLength() == 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    onUpdateNetworkStatus(false);
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You need `android:networkSecurityConfig`

Comment: I've tried android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" and works.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use one of the following libraries to make network checking process easier in your Apps

1. [merlin](https://github.com/novoda/merlin)
2. [Android Network Manager](https://github.com/jumaallan/AndroidNetworkManager)

Comment: thanks, I'll check them and reply to you if they are working perfectly with Android Pie 9.0